# Shuffle not working (Python)

Tags: python

I am trying to make a simple program which makes a name for the user. This is what I have. But when I run it, it says that ncpnames is not defined, but it is, I defined it at the start. Please help!

```
import time
import random
from random import shuffle
ncpnames = ["Rulf","Isabel","William","Alice","Eleanor","Dimia","Aleida","Farfelee"]
shuffle(ncpnames)
npcname1 = npcnames[0]
print("Hello my name is", npcname1)
```

Comment: you swapped the letters `c` and `p` in the two spellings

Comment: as @TimPeters said: the line `npcname1 = npcnames[0]` has `ncpnames` misspelled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misspelled your variable:

```
npcname1 = npcnames[0]
```

You should have:

```
npcname1 = ncpnames[0]
```

Honestly, you should have caught this on your own by simply reading over your code.

Comment: Oh, I am such an idiot. Sorry! I was trying to get it working for like 50 minutes! It kept saying line 5 had no variable and I was so confused! I'm new to this sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

NPC = ["Rulf","Isabel","William","Alice","Eleanor","Dimia","Aleida","Farfelee"]
chosenName = random.choice(NPC)
print("Hello my name is", chosenName)
```

Slighly neater